# How to print space after every touched button which displays text

Tags: ios, objective-c

It's one of my first days with Objective C and I am trying to print space every time I touch the button. Thanks a lot.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize display = _display;

-(IBAction)trickClicked:(UIButton *)sender{
    NSString *trick = [sender currentTitle];

    UILabel *myDisplay = self.display;
    NSString *currentText = myDisplay.text;
    NSString *newText = [currentText stringByAppendingString:trick];
    myDisplay.text = newText;

}

@end
```

Comment: So, what's the actual problem? Does your method not get called? (If so, is your button's touchUpInside actually linked to the method?)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// NSString *newText = [currentText stringByAppendingString:trick];
NSString *newText = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", currentText, trick];
```